# Customize application starting

Tags: operating-system

Is there any way that I can Fix the time to start any application like internet Explorer, or any other application. so if I don't miss my schedule of work.

ex: If every day evening I want my explorer to open certain page automatically,

Is it possible ???

Answer (score 1):

Scheduler in control panel.  I do this daily for our required timesheets.

Control panel -> Scheduled tasks -> add scheduled task

Answer (score 0):

If you need a way to automate a task, you can use [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/AutoIt/) or [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) to automate it, and the scheduler built into Windows (Start > Programs > Accessories > System Tools > Scheduled Tasks) to automatically run it every day.